# Siemens USS software stack

Tags: interface, protocols, specifications, telegram, uss

Is there a `free/open software` stack for Siemens USS telegram written in C?

Preferable, it should be written in/for a embedded bare metal system with/without a support of a Real time kernel.

I want to incorporate the stack in an existing system to try out a frequency converter from Siemens.

It does not need to be a fully implementation of all messages for all devices but some of the more usual ones, such as `r0052` would be a great help.

It is the "mess" of the sizes PKW and PZD that really confuses it up.

I still wonder Why USS do not have a standard telegram of fix length that always can be sent and return such information.

I do have the official document, `uss_24178253_spec_76` and there are some examples at the end but surely there should be something already out there already.

Regards Stefan